# How to add panel into 3D view port (beside object 3D)

Tags: panel

I'm just trying to get my addon panel to show up into the 3D view port, but I can't figure out the correct 'bl_' combination to make it work.

Answer (score 3):

Setting `bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'` will place your [panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Panel.html) within the 3dview. You then set `bl_region_type = 'TOOLS'` to have it show in the tools region while the less intuitive `bl_region_type = 'UI'` places it in the properties region.

If you want to place a panel in the properties editor, you would set `bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'` and `bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'`, then you set `bl_context` to match the context you want it shown in - `Object`, `Scene`, `World`, `Modifier`...

Also remember that you need to register your panel class -

```
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyPanel)
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I look for add it into the scene 3D. i try also with a popup dialog and it works well but it disappeared when i click in other point of the Blender interface.