# How can I set the active category in the "N" panel?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, panel

I have created a custom panel and when <kbd>N</kbd> is pressed on the keyboard in 3d view we get the Sidebar with the Item tab opened by default, but I don't want that. I have also added an operator that does the same as <kbd>N</kbd> but I want to add one more thing that I could not find.

When someone presses <kbd>N</kbd> or executes my operator by pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> it should open the Sidebar tab with my add-on.

````
import bpy


class MY_PT_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Addon"
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_TAB"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "MyTab"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text='Welcome to my addon',icon='FORWARD')

class MY_OT_OPERATOR(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname='addon.open_sidebar'
    bl_label = 'Open SideBar'

    def execute(self,context):
        areas = bpy.context.screen.areas
        view_3d = None
        for area in areas:
            if area.type == 'VIEW_3D':
                view_3d = area

        space = view_3d.spaces[0]
        space.show_gizmo = False
        space.show_region_ui = True

        return {'FINISHED'}

addon_keymap = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_PANEL)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_OPERATOR)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    km = kc.keymaps.new('3D View', space_type = 'VIEW_3D')
    kmi = km.keymap_items.new('addon.open_sidebar','N','PRESS',shift=True)

    addon_keymap.append((km,kmi))

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_PANEL)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_OPERATOR)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    for km, kmi in addon_keymap:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymap.clear()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Hello! What exactly do you mean by "open an addon" ?

Comment: I mean whenever we press `N` it opens the `Item` tab which I don't. I should open another tab like `View` or `Tool` or my addon.

Comment: In this case [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/86891) and [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76771/how-to-add-panel-into-3d-view-port-beside-object-3d) should answer your question

Comment: no, I'm not looking for this.

Comment: you want to open new window for your addon?

Comment: No, I mean when someone presses the `N` key it opens the `Region UI` with the `Transform` tab. I want to open another tab instead of `Transform` like `View` or `Tool` or my addon.

Comment: So you want to make another tab default to N but why?

Comment: Change you question title and description.

Comment: @Muzammil Your response was already given by @Gorgious... But you probably haven't even read the other threads. The Toolbar for the ```N``` shortcut is defined by ```bl_category```. If you want a new tab with a name "MyTab",  just add ```bl_category = "MyTab"``` to the attributes of your panel, and Blender will create a new tab for your Panel (or place your panel in another tab, if it already exists).

Comment: Please read the question's description again.

Comment: Alright, I understand what you want, @Karan seems to have pinpointed the problem. I don't know if this is available to the python API unfortunately. I'm sorry to inform you that AFAIK this is not possible. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163360/is-it-possible-to-change-the-active-bl-category-with-python Unless you're willing to dive into the source code and build a custom version of Blender.

Comment: There is a hack, you have to get your addon tab position and simulate a click on it.

Comment: Seems like it is really impossible to change the active Sidebar tab from Blender's Python API.